# Show tagged user names on image using Swift

Tags: swift, instagram, tagging

I want to show tagged user names on image in my iPhone application. When I click on image It needs to show all tagged users. When I click again I need to hide those tags.
I'm using table view cell as media item. Is it possible to use another cell on top of table view cell which I can use to show tags on image?
If there is any better way to proceed with it, please let me konw.

[image: img]

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/EddyBorja/EBPhotoPages

Comment: Thanks for this link. It meets requirement although Library written in ObjectiveC. Thank you for response. I'll try to import it.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna, Thanks for your answer. I have the similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Add button on the image and let a bool variable for this.
Set variable default false.
And check if it false set to true and vice versa.
and take the decision according to bool if it true show all tagged otherwise hide all tagged.

isShow = !isShow

Comment: Suppose there are 20 tagged users then how can I show on single button?

Comment: I'm getting tagged users with media item. I need to reuse label to show all tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add Button On Image And make button toggle like

```
var lblTag: UILabel!
var i=0
let arrTags : NSArray! // Add your tangs in this Array

 @IBAction func btnImageTapped(sender : UIButton)
 {
    if (sender.selected)
    {
         sender.selected=false
        // Display All tags

         for(i=0;i<arrTags.count;i++)
         {
            // set random x , y coordinate
            lblTag = UILabel(frame:  CGRectMake(CGFloat(i)+1.0,CGFloat(i)+6.0,25,25))
            lblTag.tag=i;
            lblTemp.text = arrTags.objectAtIndex(i) as? String
            self.view.addSubview(lblTag) 
         }
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected=true
        // Hide All Tags

        let lblTemp : UILabel!
        for(i=0;i<arrTags.count;i++)
        {
           lblTemp = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as! UILabel 
           lblTemp.hidden = true
        }
    }
 }
```